# postgres noinherit and grants

Tags: postgresql, postgrest

In the tutorial of postgrest is says:

```
create role authenticator noinherit login password 'mysecretpassword';
grant web_anon to authenticator;
```

My question is: why grant privileges of web_anon to authenticator, while authenticator in noinherit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is so the `authenticator` can switch to the `web_anon` role, as described in https://postgrest.org/en/v9.0/auth.html#authentication-sequence

Comment: You mean via 'set role'?

Comment: Yes, it's actually done via `set_config('role', 'web_anon', true)` which is an equivalent of `SET LOCAL ROLE`.